# Javascript ... duplicate cookie names in top level and subdomain

Tags: javascript, cookies, subdomain, duplicates

Here is my situation ... I have a cookie named XYZ set to VALUE1 in the **.example.com** domain and an identically named cookie XYZ set to a differrent value VALUE2 in the **.sub.example.com** domain ... Given this condition, I have several questions:

1. What will a getcookie function give me for XYZ when I visit a page in the **sub.example.com** space ... VALUE1 or VALUE2 or isn't it predictable?
2. What will a getcookie function give me for XYZ when I visit a page in the **example.com** space ... VALUE1 or VALUE2 or isn't it predictable?
3. Given my situation, is there any way to detect that I actually HAVE this situation - i.e. that I have duplicated the cookie named XYZ in two or more "nested" subdomains?  I realize that the domain is not returned with the cookies, but I was thinking there may be a string somewhere in which "XYZ" appears twice?.
4. And finally, I'd love to be able to delete/expire the XYZ cookie in **.sub.example.com** but I never want to delete the XYZ cookie in the **.example.com** domain ... any suggestions?

And I completely realize that the ideal situation is never to get oneself into this sort of predicament, but it's way too late for that!

Thanks for any help or suggestions ... they will be much appreciated.
=Fred